# Kentico 12: change value of one page type field based on value of another field

Tags: drop-down-menu, kentico, kentico-mvc, kentico-12, kentico-api

I have a custom page type with two fields, `StateName` and `StateCode`. I would like it so that when a value is selected in either of these fields, the other field’s value changes to match.

So for example, if I select “Alabama” in the `StateName` field, the value of the `StateCode` field would automatically change to “AL.” Or if I select “CO” in the `StateCode` field, the `StateName` field would automatically change to “Colorado,” etc. Is this possible?

[image: State Fields]

(I have to keep these as two separate fields, because I need to display either the state name or the state code on the front-end depending on context. Therefore, I can’t use a single field with options like `AL;Alabama` because then the field only returns the value `AL` and I have no way of getting the display name `Alabama`).

I know Kentico has options for setting “dependent” fields, but that only appears to determine visibility – e.g. only display Field B if I select a particular value in Field A. I can’t find a way to actually change the selected value in one field based on the selected value in another field.

Answer (score 0):

Two control solution seems some kind of an overkill here. You can use [StateInfoProvider](https://docs.kentico.com/api12/configuration/countries#Countries-States) to get what you want.

```
StateInfo state = StateInfoProvider.GetStateInfo("Alabama")
```

The other way would be to use a simple drop down control and use 
query like that :

```
select stateCode + '|'+ StateDisplayName, StateDisplayName  from cms_State
```

to get get code and display name as value separated by |

Comment: You mean I can just have one field with the state names and then use `StateInfoProvider` to get the state code from that? (One possible complication is that one of the items in the list is *not* actually a state, but just a custom value – what would happen in that case?)

Comment: Ok . To make things simple go with the second option when your value will contain  a code and a display name (separated by some character). All api will produce a sql query at the backend StateInfoProvider.Get ... will make a SQL query. You are better off parsing the value, if you want both code and name  at the same time.